# Make dropdown work like tabs

Tags: php, wordpress, tabs, contact-form-7, dropdownbox

I have 5 forms that I would like to select from a drop down box on a single page. I need it to work the same way tabs work, except with a drop down box. Could someone please point me in the direction to make this work?

I want to onclick in the dropdown box to show the tabcontent ... but without the tab buttons.

-Chad

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
 /* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
 <select>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select name</option>
  <option value="Tom">London</option>
  <option value="Marry">Paris</option>
  <option value="Jane">Tokyo</option>
</select>
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There will be some changes to that you will have to do in your HTML and javascript code.

I have made those changes below

// Below is the HTML Code

```
<select id="change_form_dropdown" onchange="openCity()">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select name</option>
  <option value="London">London</option>
  <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
  <option value="Tokyo">Tokyo</option>
</select>
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

// And here is the javascript code.

```
function openCity() {
  var dropdown_element = document.getElementById("change_form_dropdown");
  var cityName = 
             dropdown_element.options[dropdown_element.selectedIndex].value;

  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
      tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that 
      opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    //evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```